# Change hyphenation rules in polyglossia

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

I found that there are other hyphenation rules in my language package (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/hyphenation/ukrhyph). How can I activate not default hyphen rules? By default Ukrainian language settings use very liberal hyphenation rules.

MWE https://www.overleaf.com/read/nrqycybcgprp

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
\parbox{0em}{хімічний}
\end{document}
```

Produces хі-мі-чний, but with ukrhypmt.tex should produce хі-міч-ний

Comment: The files on CTAN provide for hyphenation with T2A encoded fonts, so they're unsuitable for Unicode based fonts. It is possible that the current patterns for Unicode have mistakes. There is a TUG mailing list for problems with hyphenation: http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-hyphen. Anyway, the same hyphenation is obtained with `pdflatex` and T2A encoding.

Comment: `\showhyphens{хімічний}` is a better way to see hyphen points in general, the 0 width parbox would not work in xetex for example as xetex like pdftex does not hyphenate the first word. You can use `\hyphenation{хі-міч-ний}` to specify that rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the LuaTeX hyphenation patterns you need to replace the file located at     `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-uk.pat.txt`

Where language code is hyph-**uk**.pat.txt. In case you convert from .tex patterns you need to remove everything except patterns (like comments and tex commands):

```
% File: ukrhypsm.tex THIS LINE SHOULD BE REMOVED
% TeX hyphenation patterns for Ukrainian THIS LINE SHOULD BE REMOVED
\patterns{ % THIS LINE SHOULD BE REMOVED
. ª1à
. ­ 5«
```